# runtime error 1004 method range of object global failed

Tags: vba

Hello I need help I am getting an error in my code in this line of the code

```
Range(copyRngStart & copyRngEnd).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Display").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
```

runtime error 1004 method range of object global failed

could someone please take a look to fix it, thanks.

```
Sub Distinct()

    Dim lr2 As Long
    Dim searchRng As Range, copyRngStart As Range, copyRngEnd As Range

    Set searchRng = Worksheets("Information").Range("A1")
    lr2 = Sheets("Display").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Enter/continue loop while A-column is non-empty
    Do While searchRng.Value <> ""

        ' When we encounter the string TRNS in column A and Triumph Foods LLC in column E
        If searchRng.Value = "TRNS" And searchRng.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Triumph Foods LLC" Then

            ' Set the start of the copy area
            Set copyRngStart = searchRng
        End If

        ' When we encounter the string ENDTRNS
        If searchRng.Value = "ENDTRNS" Then
            ' .. set the end of the copy area
            Set copyRngEnd = searchRng.Offset(-1, 5)

            ' Copy and paste
            Range(copyRngStart & copyRngEnd).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Display").Range("A" & lr2 + 1)
            lr2 = Sheets("Display").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        End If

        ' Increment search loop
        Set searchRng = searchRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Change the `&` to `,`

Comment: Only the first `&` leave the second one.

Comment: I made those changes and still getting the same error

Comment: As @ScottCraner said. Your issue is where you specify the range to copy: `Range(copyRngStart & copyRngEnd)`. If the start is A1 and the end is B2, you are saying `A1B2`...which is only one value so it must be a cell address. Can you find cell A1B2? Excel can't either. However, `A1,B2` is two values separated by a comma. It must be a range. Excel can find that range.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so I added this change Range("A:A1200" & copyRngStart & "E:E1200" & copyRngEnd).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Display").Range("A" & lr2 + 1) would this fix it? please let me know.

Comment: Try replacing your `&` to `& ":" &`

Comment: Ok I will make that change and see what happens thanks for all, brb

Comment: ok I made the change like this  Range("A1:A1200" & ":" & "E1:E1200").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Display").Range("A" & lr2 + 1) and it works but how can I make it work with the variables copyRngStart  and copyRngEnd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Distinct()

    Const TRNS_START As String = "TRNS"
    Const TRNS_END As String = "ENDTRNS"
    Const COMPANY As String = "Triumph Foods LLC"

    Dim searchRng As Range, copyRngStart As Range, copyRngEnd As Range

    Set searchRng = Worksheets("Information").Range("A1")

    ' Enter/continue loop while A-column is non-empty
    Do While searchRng.Value <> ""

        ' When we encounter the string TRNS in column A and Triumph Foods LLC in column E
        If searchRng.Value = TRNS_START And _
           searchRng.Offset(0, 4).Value = COMPANY Then

            Set copyRngStart = searchRng ' Set the start of the copy area
        End If

        ' When we encounter the string ENDTRNS
        '    (*and had a start cell already*)
        If searchRng.Value = TRNS_END And Not copyRngStart Is Nothing Then

            Set copyRngEnd = searchRng.Offset(-1, 5)

            copyRngEnd.Worksheet.Range(copyRngStart, copyRngEnd).Copy _
              Destination:=Sheets("Display").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            Set copyRngStart = Nothing 'clear the "start" range

        End If


        Set searchRng = searchRng.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```